# Running gradlew in a gitlab-ci pipeline behind a proxy

Tags: gradle, gitlab-ci, gradlew

We're working on moving our legacy gradle/grails application into a cloud environment using gitlab-ci pipeline.  Having an issue calling the gradle commands during the pipeline process behind a proxy.  I'm not 100% sure I'm diagnosing this correctly, so may not even be asking the correct question.

***How do you configure gradlew to download gradle in a gitlab pipeline behind a proxy?***

My project contains a `gradle.properties` file in the project root with the proxy information:

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=my.proxy.url.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.proxyHost=my.proxy.url.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
```

I've also copied this into `gradle-wrapper.properties` to no avail.  When building my project locally, it can download the dependencies correctly, but when pushing to gitlab, the `.gitlab-ci.yml` relevant portion is:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew properties
```

Just trying to print the properties of the wrapper, the output during build is:

```
$ ./gradlew properties
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2.1-bin.zip
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

As I said...  I'm not even sure I've got this diagnosed correctly or am asking the right question, so any other suggestions would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with network configuration of Your gitlab runner. Login to gitlab runner machine via ssh and check if `my.proxy.url.com` is reachable. If it works when You build it locally, gradle configuration is probably fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have ssh access (or possibly misunderstand) to the gitlab runner machine.  In the meantime I've found a workaround using a source image for the gitlab-ci with gradle pre-installed.  Honestly, I'm so new to this I don't know if I'm even describing it correctly.